How can I make sure AWS Glue Crawler reads all lines in a S3 csv file
I have multiple csv files in an S3 bucket coming in daily, and I process them with Glue crawlers, so they end up in Glue Data Catalog. But given the size of the files(>50 GB each) I wonder if all lines are processed successfully and the count in the Data Catalog table is accurate.
How can I check the row data in S3 csv? I am not able to download any file, but have access to AWS CLI for instance.
I tried using S3 Select on csv files but it has memory limitations.
